# filtrar url de Api en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, express

Hola comunidad estoy tratando de realizar un filtrado pero no entiendo muy bien como realizarlo ya que soy nuevo en nodejs, me gustaria poder realizarlo por para mostrar titulos que empiezan por un letra y se repita.

```
const url_page = `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${API_KEY}&count=10`;

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
const response = fetch(url_page)
var nuevo  = response.map(function(obj){
    var rObj = {
        "explanation" : obj.explanation,
        "hdurl" : obj.hdurl,
        "title" : obj.title,
        "url" : obj.url
    };
    
    return rObj;
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(nuevo => {
    nuevo.find(nuevo => nuevo.title)
})
res.json(nuevo);
```

});
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Qué significa _"para mostrar titulos que empiezan por un letra y se repita"_? ¿No todos los títulos empiezan por una letra? ¿Te refieres a que empiecen por algo cómo `Aa` o `Bb`? ¿Por qué estás usando un middleware `app.use` en lugar de un verbo http (por ejemplo `app.get`) para responder a una petición? Sin contar que los `then`s y el `map` está totalmente fuera de contexto ya que estamos hablando de código asincrónico. Revisa [este fragmento de código](https://pastebin.com/WE7k5LhB) en el que corrijo tu código para que al menos funcione. El resto no queda claro.

Comment: Quiero hacer un filtro donde pueda buscar por título donde empiece por un letra como A y que encuentre todas los resultados por esa letra

Comment: ¿Y de dónde sacas la letra por la que quieres filtrar?

Comment: Debo sacarla de la URL api que estoy manejando,pero ahí es donde no se cómo extraerlo